# Jquery: Only fill in data from .load if there is content?

Tags: php, jquery

Im using the jquery .load function to query a php file that will output some data.  Now sometimes the script will return nothing.  In this case, can I have the load function not put any data into my specified div?  (right now it clears out the div and just puts a blank white area.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using $.get;

```
$.get('<url>',{param1:true},function(result){
    if(result) {
        $('selector').html(result);
    }
    else {
        //code to handle if no results
    }       
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$.get`
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score 1):

in addition to @jerjer's post, you can also use this:

```
var paramData= 'param=' + param1 + '&user=<?echo $user;?>';

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data:paramData,
    url: "myUrl.php",
    dataType: "json", // this line is optional
    success: function(result) {
        // do you code here
        alert(result); // this can be an any value returned from myUrl.php
    },
    statusCode: {
        404: function() {
            alert('page not found');
        }
    }
});
```